# Laravel eloquent query scope that returns no rows

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I try to define scope that works with 2 conditions

For example:

If condition1 is TRUE I want to get rows where sum field > 10

If condition2 is TRUE I want to get rows where avg field < 100

If both conditions are FALSE I want there'll be no rows at all.

What's the best way to do it?

```php
public function scopeAvailable(Builder $query, bool $condition1, bool $condition2)
{
  return $query
    ->when($condition1, fn ($query) => $query->where('sum', '>', 10))
    ->when($condition2, fn ($query) => $query->where('avg', '<', 100))
    ->when(!$condition1 && !$condition2, fn ($query) => $query->nowRows(...)) // <---block here
}
```

Here without 3rd `when` statement if both conditions are FALSE I'll get all rows.

Comment: What about using a good old if statement? If the first condition is true then execute this statement. else if the second condition is true, execute that statement. and so on.

I know it's a dumb solution but it's the simplest. From my basic understanding, `when` checks all conditions regardless of how many are true or false (as it should, that's the intended behavior). So, I'd just use an if statement since the logic changes based on the conditions.

Comment: @MichaelYousrie I think `if` won't help here because I need to return some query at the end of the method. If I understand right - you suggest to return just `$query` without any `when`s if condition1 and condition2 are FALSE. It means that all rows will be returned at the end (because no `where`s will be applied to the query). I need somehow to say that if all given conditions are FALSE - no rows should be return.

Comment: I can think of 2 solutions here. the first one is; if all given conditions are false, add a random impossible where statement to the query which will ensure that you get no rows back. This is a stupid idea but an idea nonetheless.

the second option, which I suggest, is isolating the conditions logic before even running the query. Meaning, check that condition1 OR condition2 is true in an if statement THEN start running the query with the scope that you created here. That way, when the scope is called, you're 100% sure a condition is true.

Comment: @MichaelYousrie I've just figured out: `$query->limit(0)`- looks like quite convenient and not really impossible statement

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. However, something to note here. Even though you don't want any results back, you're still hitting the database with a query for no reason. That's a wasted trip between your server and the db server. In case performance matters, doing the previously mentioned `if condition1 or condition2` statement should ensure that you're hitting the db for a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution that I found worked for me:

```php
public function scopeAvailable(Builder $query, bool $condition1, bool $condition2)
{
  return $query
    ->when($condition1, fn ($query) => $query->where('sum', '>', 10))
    ->when($condition2, fn ($query) => $query->where('avg', '<', 100))
    ->when(!$condition1 && !$condition2, fn ($query) => $query->limit(0);
}
```

Yes, it actually executes SQL, but it's trade-off between performance and protection of unexpected situations.